# Pressure canning instructions

Tags: canning, pressure-canner, food-preservation

Where can safe and reliable instructions (including high and low altitude canning) be found for canning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[National Center for Home Food Preservation](http://www.uga.edu/nchfp/)

> The National Center for Home Food Preservation is your source for current research-based recommendations for most methods of home food preservation. The Center was established with funding from the Cooperative State Research, Education and Extension Service, U.S. Department of Agriculture (CSREES-USDA) to address food safety concerns for those who practice and teach home food preservation and processing methods.

Answer (score 6):

The [Ball Complete Book of Home Preserving](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0778801314) includes a section that does just what you're asking.  It also provides a large collection of excellent recipes and general tips and tricks.

Answer (score 0):

My pressure cooker came with detailed instructions for canning.

Comment: Including high and low altitude canning?